# BI Publisher - Display Data Horizontally MONTH

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, xml-publisher

I have the following data model:

ABC

Monitor

20

APRIL

.25

20

PRIMARY

CNTR000000

-

DICS

Hourly

75

MARCH

.25

8

PRIMARY

CNTR001111

How to display the result horizontally, like this April, March

Answer (score 0):

Find the `BI Publisher Report Designer's Guide` documentation and look for `cross-tab`

[image]

Would want something like this:

**For Month columns:**

```
<?for-each-group@column:RESULTS;MONTH?>
<?MONTH?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

**For Rows:**

```
<?for-each-group:RESULTS;TYPE?>
<?TYPE?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

**For Cells:**

```
<?for-each-group@cell:current-group();MONTH?>   
<?sum(current-group()//HOURS)?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```